# Is Bluetooth low energy (BLE) still secure?

Tags: encryption, attacks, bluetooth

Some time ago, Bluetooth was hit by a severe exploit (KNOB attack) that rendered its encryption pretty much useless. Publishers like the German Heise summarized it in an article* as an issue in the firmware of Bluetooth radio affecting BR/EDR only. Therefore, BLE appears to be still secure. My question is if that's really the case and can I assume data-stream connections using BLE's L2CAP to be a secure communication channel (working encryption)? Moreover, is such a connection secured against typical MITM attack like replay attacks etc.?

*https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/KNOB-Attack-Schwerer-Konzeptfehler-in-Bluetooth-4499499.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. It's insecure. Both classic and LE are affected by KNOB attack and the session key can be downgraded. See  https://francozappa.github.io/publication/knob-ble/

So, make sure to use another extra TLS layer ...